# Catalina.out doesn't exist

Tags: java, tomcat, console, system.out, catalina.out

I want to read my console output logs, and I know that they are stored into "log" folder under the file catalina.out, but it doesn't exists! I have tried in different ways with no results. I don't know how to figure it out, I just want to see my java outputs logs

Comment: Look at the script that is used to start your Tomcat.

Comment: What is your OS? Sometimes tomcat on Linux writes directly to system log (whatever it is). In my case, I check the logs with `journalctl -f -u tomcat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `catalina.sh` , it says :

```
#   CATALINA_OUT    (Optional) Full path to a file where stdout and stderr
#                   will be redirected.
#                   Default is $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out
```

So , look at your script that is used to start Tomcat to find out what the value of the environment variable `CATALINA_OUT`.

Comment: Thus, I have to find that value from Tomcat startup script? Why?

Comment: How can you start tomcat now ? I mean looking at the your script that is used to start tomcat.

Comment: @KenChan, in `apache-tomcat-9` there is no text which you pasted. I don't see `CATALINA_OUT` in `catalina.sh` file. There are only `CATALINA_HOME`, `CATALINA_BASE` and `CATALINA_OPTS`

Answer (score 6):

If the `catalina.out` is deleted after `tomcat` is stopped, it will create a new `catalina.out` once `tomcat` starts again and it is totally safe.

But if you remove the `catalina.out` while `tomcat` is running, it will keep on logging to `catalina.out` which is removed already (reference of the file is hold by the `tomcat`) hence the space will not be released. So you will need to restart the `tomcat` sever to release the space. It is not recommended.

Start/ Run Tomcat server and it should create `catalina.out` file without any error.

Following are the multiple ways of running tomcat. Just indicated in detail so this would help someone in need.

```
./catalina.sh run
```

Passing "run" argument for catalina.sh --> starts the Tomcat in the **foreground** and **displays the running logs in the same console**. when the console terminal is closed it **will terminate the tomcat**.

```
./catalina.sh start
```

Passing "start" argument for catalina.sh --> starts the **Tomcat in the background**. Since in background no issues closing down the terminal. The logs need to be viewed as below: `tail -f $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out`

```
./startup.sh
```

The last way is firing the startup.sh to start your Tomcat server. If you Vi the script you can see it calls **catalina.sh script passing start as the argument**. This will be running in background as well.

Now check your tomcat log directory and you should find the `catalina.out`

Answer (score 3):

go to the bin folder of tomcat and run below script
`./catalina.sh start`

now `catalina.out` exist in logs folder

Answer (score 1):

When we upgraded our Beanstalks to **Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2**, *catalina.out* no longer existed and not all logs were present in catalina.*date*.log. We re-established the *catalina.out* with the following file dropped into */etc/rsyslog.d/catalina.conf*

```
$umask 0000
$FileCreateMode 0644
template(name="Tomcat" type="string" string="%msg%\n") {
  property(name="msg")
}
if $programname == 'tomcat' then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out" template="Tomcat")
}
if  $programname == 'server' then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out" template="Tomcat")
}
```

you will want to restart rsyslog afterwards.

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I just put this script inside .ebextensions folder to get it automatically. However noticed that many of this messages was already saved in '/var/log/messages' file.